# Split string to array is specific way

Tags: javascript

I have string like this one:

> This is a text [SPACE] and this also text [SPACE] more text [SPACE]
>   here text

My goal is to create array like this:

```
['This is a text', '[SPACE]', 'and this also text', '[SPACE]', 'more text', '[SPACE]']
```

Or like this

```
['This is a text', 'SPACE', 'and this also text', 'SPACE', 'more text', 'SPACE']
```

I've tried to split it like this .split('['), but it's not exactly what I'm looking for

Answer (score 2):

Match *and capture* `[SPACE]` in a regular expression. Captured groups inside a `split` will be included in the output array, so that's exactly what you should aim for here. To omit the spaces around the `[SPACE]`, just match them normally, outside the capture group, and they won't be present in the output:

```js
const input = 'This is a text [SPACE] and this also text [SPACE] more text [SPACE] here text';
console.log(
  input.split(/ *(\[SPACE\]) */)
);
```

Comment: Can you include actual spaces around the `[SPACE]` in regex, to get the desired output array as specified in the question?

Comment: Oh, thanks, I missed that, have to match the spaces normally so they aren't present in the output